# Group by records in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the count of records in each group where they are in sequence. For example if I have a table like this

[image]

If the start of next record is the following to the end of the previous record,  they should be in a group. So I need the output to be like this

[image]

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Its little tricky but you can do it using hierarchical query. Give a try if can't figure out I can provide it.

Comment: @Anil what is  hierarchical query ? also like to add the table has 2 millions records

Comment: If there's always a pattern to the strings (e.g. 3 characters then a number), this isn't difficult with a combination of substrings and `LEAD()`/`LAG()` window functions.

Comment: @ZLK the prefix is not constant.

Comment: There needs to be some pattern. e.g. Is it always letters (of any length) then numbers? If yes, then you can use a PATINDEX to extract the number. If no, then how do you determine the numbers?

Comment: @zlk Yes, there is a pattern  prefix+number. If i extract the number how can I do the grouping?

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ? Also post the sample data as text in table format.

Comment: @sebeid If using SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use `LEAD()` and `LAG()` to look at the next/previous rows to see if there's a difference of 1. I'll put together an answer to illustrate this.

Comment: SQL version in 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings look like a series of characters then a number (e.g. "XXX001" or "XXXXXXXX001" or "ABC1"), then one way you can do this is by first extracting the numbers with [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql), then using [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) and [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) to find the start and end of the patterns. Then use a [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to join the corresponding start and end and do a count of the rows in between the start and end.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Start VARCHAR(20), [End] VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES 
(1, 'sam001', 'sam005'),
(2, 'sam006', 'sam008'),
(3, 'sam009', 'sam014'),
(4, 'sam018', 'sam024'),
(5, 'sam030', 'sam035'),
(6, 'sam036', 'sam040'),
(7, 'wazza01', 'wazza2'),
(8, 'wazza03', 'wazza000005'),
(9, 'wazza09', 'wazza12'),
(10, 'sam041', 'sam42');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
            StartOfSequence = CASE WHEN LAG(EndNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER  BY ID) IS NULL OR StartNum - LAG(EndNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            EndOfSequence = CASE WHEN LEAD(StartNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID) IS NULL OR LEAD(StartNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID) - EndNum > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM (
        SELECT ID,
                Start,
                [End],
                StartNum = CAST(SUBSTRING(Start, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Start), LEN(Start)) AS INT),
                EndNum = CAST(SUBSTRING([End], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [End]), LEN([End])) AS INT),
                Prefix = SUBSTRING(Start, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Start) - 1)
        FROM @T
    ) AS T
) 
SELECT C1.Start, C2.[End], Total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE WHERE ID >= C1.ID AND ID <= C2.ID AND Prefix = C1.Prefix)
FROM (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE StartOfSequence = 1
) AS C1
JOIN (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE EndOfSequence = 1
) AS C2 ON C1.RN = C2.RN
    AND C1.Prefix = C2.Prefix;
```

Or using a modification of @Pரதீப்'s suggestion below to include the prefix,

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Start VARCHAR(20), [End] VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES 
(1, 'sam001', 'sam005'),
(2, 'sam006', 'sam008'),
(3, 'sam009', 'sam014'),
(4, 'sam018', 'sam024'),
(5, 'sam030', 'sam035'),
(6, 'sam036', 'sam040'),
(7, 'wazza01', 'wazza2'),
(8, 'wazza03', 'wazza000005'),
(9, 'wazza09', 'wazza12'),
(10, 'sam041', 'sam42');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
            prevEndNum = LAG(EndNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER  BY ID)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID,
                Start,
                [End],
                StartNum = CAST(SUBSTRING(Start, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Start), LEN(Start)) AS INT),
                EndNum = CAST(SUBSTRING([End], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [End]), LEN([End])) AS INT),
                Prefix = SUBSTRING(Start, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Start) - 1)
        FROM @T
    ) AS T
) 
SELECT DISTINCT Prefix,
                First_value(start) OVER(PARTITION BY Prefix, grp ORDER BY id), 
                First_value([end]) OVER(PARTITION BY Prefix, grp ORDER BY id DESC), 
                Count(*) OVER( partition BY grp) 
FROM   (SELECT grp = Sum(CASE WHEN startnum = prevendnum + 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
                       OVER(PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY id),* 
        FROM   CTE)a
```

Note: If the IDs were all out of order for some reason, you could swap all the `ORDER BY ID` parts with `ORDER BY StartNum` or something like that, if necessary.

**EDIT FOR SQL Server 2005:**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Start VARCHAR(20), [End] VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES 
(1, 'sam001', 'sam005'),
(2, 'sam006', 'sam008'),
(3, 'sam009', 'sam014'),
(4, 'sam018', 'sam024'),
(5, 'sam030', 'sam035'),
(6, 'sam036', 'sam040'),
(7, 'wazza01', 'wazza2'),
(8, 'wazza03', 'wazza000005'),
(9, 'wazza09', 'wazza12'),
(10, 'sam041', 'sam42');

WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT ID,
           Start,
           [End],
           StartNum = CAST(SUBSTRING(Start, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Start), LEN(Start)) AS INT),
           EndNum = CAST(SUBSTRING([End], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [End]), LEN([End])) AS INT),
           Prefix = SUBSTRING(Start, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Start) - 1)
    FROM @T
),
    CTE2 AS (
    SELECT C.*, 
           StartOfSequence = CASE WHEN PrevRow.EndNum IS NULL OR C.StartNum - PrevRow.EndNum > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           EndOfSequence = CASE WHEN NextRow.StartNum IS NULL OR Nextrow.StartNum - C.EndNum > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM CTE1 AS C
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 StartNum FROM CTE1 WHERE Prefix = C.Prefix AND ID > C.ID ORDER BY ID) NextRow
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 EndNum FROM CTE1 WHERE Prefix = C.Prefix AND ID < C.ID ORDER BY ID DESC) PrevRow
)
SELECT C1.Start, C2.[End], Total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE2 WHERE ID >= C1.ID AND ID <= C2.ID AND Prefix = C1.Prefix)
FROM (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID)
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE StartOfSequence = 1
) AS C1
JOIN (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID)
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE EndOfSequence = 1
) AS C2 ON C1.RN = C2.RN
    AND C1.Prefix = C2.Prefix;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just  a point to add, there are different prefixes. Sam001  and ZLK001 and so on. So the numbers are in sequence per each prefix.

Comment: @sebeid Ah, then it's just a matter of extracting the prefix as well and partitioning by that as well. For example, a modification of the above rextester link would be this: http://rextester.com/YNK74958 (Though this assumes for any given row, the start and end prefix is the same).

Comment: @ZLK Great answer. just wondering if there is a way to do this in SQL 2005

Comment: @sebeid SQL Server 2005 makes it a bit complicated, actually. LEAD/LAG can be easily replaced with applies or self joins and there are creative ways to do row_number functions as well, but PATINDEX (afaik) wasn't available in 2005. Which means I think you'd have to (very slowly) iterate over each character in each start/end combination until you reach a number... Which is possible with a recursive CTE but very expensive.

Comment: Actually, never mind. It appears PATINDEX and ROW_NUMBER could be used in 2005 and I'm wrong. I'll edit in an answer which should work in 2005.